# How to loop and check if one of the list contains a certain value in Python

Tags: python, json, string

I have a python script wherein I need to identify if any of the list in the sample json output under ['Principal']['AWS'] contains root value. If one or more strings contains "root", then I'll declare the variable cross_acct as 'true'.

Example:
arn:aws:iam::331265876530:**root**" -> this contains "root"

I think I'll have to loop through and then maybe check each one in the list if it contains the word root? Can you please share your ideas on how I can do that in my code? Thanks!

Here's the sample json response which the code will check:

```
"Principal": {
    "AWS": [
        "arn:aws:iam::848764537201:root",
        "arn:aws:iam::331265876530:root",
        "arn:aws:iam::766754320382:role/Admin"
    ]
 }
```

If the json response doesn't contain any root within the list(like in the example below) then we can set the value of cross_acct to false.

```
"Principal": {
    "AWS": [
        "arn:aws:iam::848764537201:role/DBA",
        "arn:aws:iam::766754320382:role/Admin"
    ]
 }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use the `any()` function.

Comment: `any(s.endswith(":root") for s in ...)`

Answer (score 0):

I would iterate over the list and then use the following code:

```
if "root" in listname[i]:
    print(listname[i])
```

instead of printing you could obviously do something else instead...

i, in this case, would be your iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension:

```
print ([x for x in listname if 'root' in x])
```